# Failed to allocate a 8208 byte allocation with 5640 free bytes and 5KB until OOM, max allowed footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I try to search my device for image and upload them on Firebase. it working fine on emulator but when i try to run it on my real device the app crashing after uploading 5/6 images.
(i have more than 1000 image my real device but only 10-15 images on emulator)
**Thanks for any help**

```
private void uploadImages() {

    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

                size = cursor.getCount();
                if (size == 0) {

                } else {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                        int file_ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                        String path = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);
                        uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));


                        if (uri != null) {
                            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));
                            fileReference.putFile(uri)    // here is the line (MainActivity.java:216)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            counter++;
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    mWaveLoadingView.setProgressValue((int) (counter / size * 100));
                                                    int percent = (int) (counter / size * 100);
                                                    mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(percent + "%");
                                                    if (counter == size) {
                                                        mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(percent + "% Done");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Image Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    };


}


private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}
```

**this is the error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
Process: com.example.uploadimagefirebase, PID: 14505
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8208 byte allocation with 5640 free bytes and 5KB until OOM, max allowed footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:205)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:185)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:144)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:240)
    at com.example.uploadimagefirebase.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:216)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**and this one**

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
```

Comment: You have a growth limit of 512MB (536870912 bytes) and are hitting it.

Comment: can u pls explain what can i do?